# what exactly opt out from scoped storage by enabling the legacy external storage on Android 10 with target SDK 29

Tags: android, scoped-storage

There is an option to optput the scoped storage while targeting to SDK 29.
By enabling legacy storage with the help of adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest file. The existing functionalities of my app not working on Android 10.

For example

1. Not able to access public directory getExternalStorageDirectory()
2. Not able to call mkdir() method
3. Not able to download file via DownloadManager and so on.

I want to know what exactly opt out from scoped storage by enabling the legacy external storage.

Because as per my understanding still we have to use the new categorization of external storage on android 10 too.

**DownloadManager code snippet for storage path:**

```
DownloadManager.Request  request=new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mappfolder/subdirectory", filename);
```

**Manifest application tag :**

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name=".base.module.view.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/im_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/myThemeNOActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
        >
```

Comment: What you say about mkdir() and DownloadManager does not come true.

Comment: Further: if you enable legacy storage on an Android 10 device it will behave like you were used on 9, 8, ..

Comment: @blackapps I am using DowloadManager while writing files into external storage getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories :myappfolder/subdirectory . code snippet for download manager request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mappfolder/subdirectory", filename);

Comment: DownloadManager code updated. is there any caching issue by enabling legacy storage I am not able to use getExternalStorageDirectory() method to access public directory and create myapp folder there using mkdirs() method.

Comment: `"/mappfolder/subdirectory"` mappfolder is no public dir. Please choose one of the public dirs. Environment class will tell you all possible ones.

Comment: By default its getting created in the same directory which I get from using getExternalStorageDirectory() method. Lets if I will add Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS then how I will read the downloaded file using File system. I think these directories can be access via MediaStore. I want to create my app folder into public directory. Also access of read and write to my app folder. How this is possible without changing the storage access way. Please help me on this.

Comment: You can put them in public directory  `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` and then in a  subdirectory like `"/mappfolder/subdirectory"`. You can get a path to it using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`. You will request legacy external storage of course. If not the DownloadManager will give you a nice uri which you can use to access the file.

Comment: @blackapps Further: if you enable legacy storage on an Android 10 device it will behave like you were used on 9, 8, ..    This is not working for me. I am not getting what is wrong here. Adding my application tag to post.

Comment: My app is not behaving like Android 9,8,... even I have enabled legacy storage. With legacy storage whatever code I have written earlier to read / write into external storage should work on Android 10. But its not working on android 10 while the same code is working on Android 9. It seems like legacy storage is not enabled by writing android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest's application tag.

Comment: Did you have that in manifest before but then false? If so the true does nothing and you have to deinstall/reinstall your app. What device is it? And what is Android version of device?

Comment: Yes I did that earlier. Also tried by uninstalling and reinstalling again. I am using emulator.

Answer (score 1):

getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated in API 29. Use getExternalFilesDir().

If you use the *legacy external storage*, your app needs permissions such as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. However soon scoped storage is going to be enforced, so you should change your code to use MediaStore API and/or Storage Access Framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

By enabling legacy storage, can use the legacy file system API's to create app specific directories into public directory and to access public storage to read / write files.

But with DownloadManger, can not create app specific directory into public storage.